# Removing nodes from middle of Linked List and infinite loop in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, nodes, infinite-loop

I'm trying to create a linked list structure in C to allow a user to enter a list of direct debits with a description, then allow the user to select and delete any node. The solution I got from many sources, while researching, isn't working. No matter which node I choose, the latest one is always deleted.
Can anyone tell me where the problem in my code is?
It's also started throwing infinite loops of one node when printining the entire list

```
#define true 1
#define false 0

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Banknode {
    float debit;
    char description[100];
    struct Banknode *next;
}Banknode;

struct Banknode *latestPtr = NULL;

int isEmpty(void);

void add(float fig, char info[100]);

float rmv(int n);

void allList();

void showMenu();

int main()
{
  latestPtr = NULL;
  int choice;
  float deb;
  char info[100];
  int n;

  //MENU
  printf("\nWelcome to your DirectDebit management system");
  printf("\nPlease select an option:");
  printf("\n1. View Latest DirectDebit");
  printf("\n2. View all DirectDebits");
  printf("\n3. Add a DirectDebit");
  printf("\n4. Remove a DirectDebit");
  printf("\n5. Show menu");
  printf("\n6. Exit\n");
  while(choice != 6)
  {
    scanf("\n%d", &choice);
    switch(choice)
    {

      case 1:
      {
        if(!isEmpty())
        {
          printf("\nThe latest DirectDebit is: \n%.2f for %s,\n", latestPtr->debit, latestPtr->description);
          showMenu();
        }
        else
        {
          printf("\nAll DirectDebits have been removed.\n");
          printf("To see the menu, select option 5,\n");
          printf("Or to quit, select option 6.\n");
        }
        break;
      }

      case 2:
      {
        if(!isEmpty())
          allList();
        else
        {
          printf("\nYou have no DirectDebits\n");
          printf("To see the menu, select option 5,\n");
          printf("Or to quit, select option 6.\n");
        }
        break;
      }

      case 3:
      {
        printf("\nWhat is the amont of new DirectDebit?\n");
        scanf("\n%f", &deb);
        printf("\nPlease give a brief, unique description of the new DirectDebit\n");
        fgets(info, 100, stdin);
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", info);
        printf("\n Your DirectDebit amount is : %.2f", deb);
        printf("\n And the description is: %s", info);
        add(deb, info);
        printf("\n");
        showMenu();
        break;
      }

      case 4:
      {
        if(!isEmpty())
        {
          if(latestPtr->next != NULL)
          {
            printf("\nPlease enter the number of the DirectDebit you wish to remove, by counting from the bottom up:\n");
            allList();
            scanf("\n%d", &n);
            printf("\nRemoving DirectDebit\n");
            printf("\n%.2f is removed from the list",rmv(n));
          }
          else
          {
            printf("\nAll DirectDebits have now been removed.\n");
            printf("To see the menu, select option 5,\n");
            printf("Or to quit, select option 6.\n");
            latestPtr = NULL;
          }
        }
        else
        {
          printf("\nYou have no DirectDebits\n");
          printf("To see the menu, select option 5,\n");
          printf("Or to quit, select option 6.\n");
        }
        break;
      }

      case 5:
      {
        showMenu();
        break;
      }
      case 6:
      printf("Thank you, Goodbye!\n");
      exit(1);
      break;

      default:
      printf("\nInvalid choice.\n");
      showMenu();
      break;
    }
  }
}


int isEmpty(void)
{
  if(latestPtr == NULL)
  return true;
  else
  return false;
}



void allList()
{
  struct Banknode *scanPtr = NULL;
  scanPtr = latestPtr;
  printf("\nYour current DirectDebits are: \n");
  while(scanPtr->next != NULL)
  {
    printf("%.2f for %s,\n",scanPtr->debit, scanPtr->description);
    scanPtr = scanPtr->next;
  }
  printf("%.2f for %s,\n",scanPtr->debit, scanPtr->description);
}



void add(float fig, char info[100])
{
  struct Banknode *newPtr = (struct Banknode*)malloc(sizeof(struct Banknode));
  if (newPtr != NULL)
  {
    newPtr->debit = fig;
    strcpy((newPtr->description), info);
    newPtr->next = latestPtr;
    latestPtr = newPtr;
  }
  else
  {
    printf("%.2f not inserted. No memory available.\n", fig);
  }
  free(newPtr);
}



float rmv(int n)
{
  int len = 0, i;
  struct Banknode *rmvPtr = latestPtr;
  while (rmvPtr != NULL)
  {
    rmvPtr = rmvPtr->next;
    len++;
  }
  if (len < n)
    return -9999;
  else
    rmvPtr = latestPtr;
    for (i = 1; i < len-n+1; i++)
      rmvPtr = rmvPtr->next;
  float j = latestPtr->debit;
  latestPtr = latestPtr->next; 
  return j;
}



void showMenu() 
{
  printf("\nPlease select an option:");
  printf("\n1. View Latest DirectDebit");
  printf("\n2. View all DirectDebits");
  printf("\n3. Add a DirectDebit");
  printf("\n4. Remove a DirectDebit");
  printf("\n5. Show menu");
  printf("\n6. Exit\n");
}
```

Comment: "The solution I got from many sources" - Sounds like you you copy&pasted  arbitrary code you don't understand. We are not a debugging service, read [ask] and provide all information with a [mcve]. And use prototypes, not old-style function declarators!

Comment: Your latestPtr is getting deleted because of the statement - latestPtr = latestPtr->next. Replace it with rmvPtr = rmvPtr->next.

Comment: Never ever use `float` for money!